# Can't fetch local JSON, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've followed the steps to fetch local JSON, I think the problem is because in the pubspec, when I change the name local JSON different name the console nothing error, so what issues do I have? it's my wrong or flutter update something? it's my code :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:fetch_local_data/model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  List<Books> parseJson(String? json) {
    if (json == null) {
      return [];
    }

    List result = jsonDecode(json);
    return result.map((e) => Books.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/books.json'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List<Books> books = parseJson(snapshot.data);
          print(books.length);
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: books.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(books[index].title);
              });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> pubspec

```
name: fetch_local_data
description: A new Flutter project.


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - assets/books.json
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5RFB.png)

Comment: Can you provide local json? Can use https://justpaste.it/.

Comment: Use hasData and hasError to check the state of FutureBuilder. Take a look at the example here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html.